# PhaseListener : beforePhase method not called on form submit

Tags: jsf, phaselistener

I'm trying to set the focus to an inputText which has an error. When I click to navigate to my form from another page then my beforePhase() code is hit. However in the form once I click submit my beforePhase() code is not hit.

Are the requiredMessage/validatorMessage attributes on my inputText element preventing it from reaching my beforePhase() code?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was the client side validation prevented it from getting that far. Turned off client side validation(jsValidation="false") and now it works.